# Exiting a for loop with button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, for-loop

Hey I've been having a difficult time trying to get my code to recognize when a user presses a stop button to exit a loop. I know it's a threading issue but I've been trying to work around that with setTimeout/setInterval.

In my code I have a button with `onclick="stop()"` with the function as `stop(){cancel = true;}`. In my code I have a .each loop that iterates through some rows a certain amount of times (depends on the amount of check boxes checked). Each iteration calls `Row(this);` which, aside from some checks and getters, contains a for-loop that iterates the total length of the current row. So something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {      
    ajaxCallForRowSingle(row[i]);

    if (stop == true) {
        return false; }
}
```

I've tried `setTimeout(ajaxCallForRowSingle(row[i]),0);` but I get "Syntax error label not found" which I assume is from the ajax call. Is there a work around for this? My button press always gets queued and executes after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's what you need to do...

Instead of using a 'for' loop, make a function and call it recursively using, 'setTimeout' or 'setInterval'

```
var iRowsToProcess = row.length;
var iRowIndex = 0;
var processRows = function(){
    if (!stop){
        ajaxCallForRowSingle(row[iRowIndex]);
        iRowIndex++;
        if (iRowIndex < iRowsToProcess){
            setTimeout(processRows, 1);
        };
    };
};

setTimeout(processRows, 1);
```

This code will call 'processRows' recursively until all rows are processed, or until 'stop' is false. The beauty is that each, "setTimeout" call is processed asyncronously, which means, it allows the other JS code to update before it is called again.  It releases the one thread that all JS code is syncronously waiting for.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Looks like it's working. Something odd though is that I open a dialog box (from JQuery ui) on the first iteration. The box opens fine with the for-loop but doesn't open at all when changed to the recursive solution. Could this be due to the anonymous function?

Comment: Which box are you referring to?  Can you post the HTML and any other JS code related to the "box" opening?

Comment: Ok I added the basic idea of my implementation for the dialog box

Comment: So, what is this line... 'if($('#current')==0){' trying to accomplish?

Comment: From what I can tell, unless you're trying to determine the 'if' statement, 'if($('#current')==0){' can be removed.  That is most likely the source of your problems.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It's actually supposed to be $('#current').html(). when I check if it's 0 that's the first iteration, then I increment the tag to show the progress of the program

Comment: So, the code for that line is, 'if ($('#current').html() == 0){'?

Comment: Okay, so that won't work.  You need to check "$('#current').html().length".  Plus, to properly verify an int to an int, you need to use '===' in lieu of '=='

Comment: Oh the if statement works fine on my end. The problem is with the line `$('#dialog').dialog("open");`. When debugging It read the line but never actually executed. The really puzzling part is that when the for-loop implementation is used, the dialog opens. Even if I move the line to the recursive function with something like  `if (iRowIndex == 0) {$('#dialog').dialog("open");}` the dialog won't execute properly.

Comment: Unless you have added, "JQueryUI" to your project, do a '$('#dialog').show();' instead.

Comment: yea I have it added. It works perfectly fine with the for-loop. When I replace the for-loop with the recursive solution, the dialog doesn't work.

Comment: For what you need to accomplish, "$.dialog" may not work for whatever reason.  Try using $.show()' and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a recursive function that calls itself rather than a for loop. Also, to break a for loop, I'd use "break" rather than trying to return false.

Set up a recursive function to continue calling itself until you hit the row.length you're looking for.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'm only using `return false` because it breaks out of the .each loop

Comment: A return false or true (or return anything) will break out of the .each loop because the .each is actually running a function, and that returns the value outside the function. A regular for loop is just a block of code that runs over and over and has no return value.

Comment: So isn't using the return option faster than breaking out of the loop then returning? Sorry I forgot to add that when the stop button is pressed I want to exit both loops but just breaking out of the for loop is my biggest problem (since stop won't set)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use setTimeout or setInterval, you'd have to wrap your ajaxCall in another function, e.g.,

```
setInterval(function () {
    ajaxCallForRowSingle(row[i]);
}, 0);
```

You can clear the interval by storing its ID as a variable, then calling clearInterval, e.g.,

```
var i = 0;
var id = setInterval(function () {
    ajaxCallForRowSingle(row[i]);
    i++;
    if (i >= row.length) { clearInterval(id); }
}, 0);

var stop = function () {
    clearInterval(id);
}
```

Comment: I actually did try this but my code ran indefinitely. The interval just kept going and going. Was there something I missed to stop it from constantly running?